# Where can I obtain MS14-22 security update for SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, patching

I have a MOSS installation that I am trying to bring up from version 12.0.6679.5001 to 12.0.6690.5000, which as I understand is the highest possible version for SharePoint 2007 (I need to reach this version so I can restore a content backup from another farm).

According to [Steve Chen's version tables for 2007](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2012/03/14/3486623.aspx), you need the MS14-22 security update to reach the final version. The problem is, I cannot figure out where to download this patch. I have run Windows Update on the SharePoint server and there are no Important or Optional updates left. If I click on the link to [MS14-22](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-022), there is a description of the patch, but no download. The KB articles for [WSS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2837616) and [MOSS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2596902) seem to suggest that this patch is distributed through Windows Update and also provide no download link. How can I obtain this patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the download by searching around microsoft.com: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42842 (64-bit)
and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42839 (32-bit). There's only a WSS version (although you need to install it even if you are running MOSS). I have no idea why this is not linked to from the pages regarding MS14-22.